# AWS Cognito: how to delete an identity programmatically?

Tags: android, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

In my Android app, I use AWS Cognito to allow my users to sign up and login. I configured my identity pool so it allows guest users (unauthenticated users) in my app.

So everytime my user logs in or logs out, I call the following code to get an identity ID:

```java
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
    this,
    "eu-central-1:12345678-1234-5678-9012-1234567890ab",
    "eu-central-1");
credentialsProvider.clearCredentials();
credentialsProvider.getIdentityId();
```

When my user logs in, it creates a new identity the first time, then the user gets the same identity everytime he logs in. But everytime he logs out, a new identity is created, since he's now a "guest" user.

Is that the expected behavior? And if yes, how can I remove an unused identity programmatically (for example when the user logs in, so the "guest" identity is now useless, since a new one will be created when he logs out)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, we have:

> `getIdentityId()` Gets the Cognito identity id of the user. The first time when this method is called, a network request will be made to retrieve a new identity id. After that it's saved in SharedPreferences.
>
> `clearCredentials()` Destroy all the saved AWS credentials but not the identity Id.

so, the behavior you described is totally normal according to the docs.

Now, let's find an approach to deal with the problem.

if you want to continue with your proposition, and delete the identity programmatically after the logout, you can use [`deleteUser()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidp/AWSCognitoIdentityProvider.html#deleteUser-com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.DeleteUserRequest-) method from AWSJavaSDK.

However, if you want to keep the same identity for the same user after the logout, you shouldn't clear the cache, cause the won't keep the user any trace of its identity.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that deleteUser() only deletes the user, not the associated identity. Also, is it normal to keep the same identity after the logout?

Comment: Yeah, actually you're right. that function needs accessToken in the params so you won't be able to call it cause you can't get the token for unauthorized users I guess. Regarding your question, I think it's okay and it makes sense to keep the same identity for the same unauthorized user, that will help you to do some stuff later (statistics, UX, ..)

Comment: It looks like you can do that from a lambda using AWS.CognitoIdentity.deleteIdentities(). Haven't tested yet, though.